# JQuery Dropdown Value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown that has a list of items, the first item has a value of 0, the other items a value greater than 0.

The following code is attached to the change event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#SearchRegionId").change(function (e) {
        var select = $("#SearchKommuneId");
        select.empty();
        if ($("#SearchRegionId").val() != 0);
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Kommune/getKommunerIRegion/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { RegionId: $("#SearchRegionId").val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    for (i in data) {
                        select.append($('<option value="' + data[i].KommuneId + '">' + data[i].KommuneNavn + '</option>'));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that when I test to see if $("#SearchRegionId").val() != 0 it always comes out true even if the selected value is 0. I have showed the value in an alert box that shows the value 0, but something tells me that it is not really 0.

Comment: `select.empty();` why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` at the end of `if`

```
if ($("#SearchRegionId").val() != 0)
```

The `;` at the end of `;` means that the if condition is ended there and the code block after that will get executed irrespective of the value of the condition.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#SearchRegionId").change(function (e) {
        var select = $("#SearchKommuneId");
        select.empty();
        if ($("#SearchRegionId").val() != 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Kommune/getKommunerIRegion/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { RegionId: $("#SearchRegionId").val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    for (i in data) {
                        select.append($('<option value="' + data[i].KommuneId + '">' + data[i].KommuneNavn + '</option>'));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/NsA5j/5/)
Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NsA5j/3/)

Comment: Arun P Johny, Ooooh my ...., great thanks for your answer. I need a trip in the sun and wind I think :-D

Answer (score 0):

Why you write

```
select.empty();
```

after you assign the value, then you check it.....

It makes the

```
var select;
```

become empty, isn't it?
That's what I think, same as [roXon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roxon)

Comment: Please note that I have two dropdowns in a drilldown scenario:

One dropdown is for municipalities:

    var select = $("#SearchKommuneId");
    select.empty();

One is for Regions, this is the dropdown that fires the change event:

    if ($("#SearchRegionId").val() != '0');